# Metafunction to extract argument parameter lists from multiple functions pointers

Tags: c++, function, types, parameters, metaprogramming

For a single function it is possible to extract its parameter types like this:

```
template <class T>
struct Foo;

template <class Ret, class... Args>
struct Foo<Ret(*)(Args...)> { /* stuff */ };
```

Would it be possible to do the same for a series of function pointers? That is,
to be able to extract the arguments and then redeploy them in the same way? E.g. something like:

```
template <class.. T>
struct Foo;

template <class... Rets, class... Args>
struct Foo<Rets(*)(Args...)...>           // I wish this worked
{
    std::tuple<Rets(*)(Args...)...> fns;  // Ditto
}
```

Comment: Start with `template <typename ...Fs> struct Foo;` and then dispatch to your existing code for each pack member.

Comment: @KerrekSB Sorry, might you elaborate? I'm not quite sure what you meant by the latter bit.

Comment: You already have a way to deal with *one* function type. You can reuse that facility with every member of a pack of a different template.

Comment: See: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef1ec2bef9bd65f5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late to the party, but this might be useful. First let's define some utilities:

```
template <class... T>
using void_t = void;

template <bool...> struct bool_pack;

template <bool... v>
using all_true = std::is_same<bool_pack<true, v...>, bool_pack<v..., true>>;
```

Then a metafunction to check whether a type is a function pointer:

```
template <class F>
struct is_function_pointer : std::integral_constant<bool, false> { };

template <class Ret, class... Args>
struct is_function_pointer<Ret (*)(Args...)> : std::integral_constant<bool, true> { };
```

Using these, let's write the class. The SFINAE toggle is placed first because the variadic pack takes up the right side:

```
template <class = void_t<>, class... T>
struct Foo_impl;

template <class... FuncPtrs>
struct Foo_impl<
    std::enable_if_t<all_true<is_function_pointer<FuncPtrs>{}...>{}>,
    FuncPtrs...
> {
    std::tuple<FuncPtrs...> fns;
};
```

Finally, a typedef to hide the SFINAE toggle from the user:

```
template <class... T>
using Foo = Foo_impl<void_t<>, T...>;
```

Voilà! `Foo<void (*)(), int (*)(double)>` goes to the specialization of `Foo_impl` which contains the adequate tuple, `Foo<int, double>` goes to the main template.

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd49d55db41e96b2)